# Given a low-resolution environment, how can we ensure that graphical object is perfectly centered and always visible?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, pixel, graphics2d

I was thinking about how to create the illusion of one giant button on the home screen of a cellphone.

[image: cellphone_desktop]

My plan was to modify the home screen background art (wallpaper) to look like there was a giant button. I would then make an invisible a 2 by 2 or 3 by 3 grid of home screen shortcuts. All the invisible shortcuts launch the same app.

The home screen icon grid is usually 5 icons by 5 icons, but what if that changes? For example, what if the user is vision impaired and uses a large icon setting.

This turned into the following question: how can we paint a box which is perfectly left/right centered on the canvas even if there are not many pixels to work with? For example, a cellphone icon grid is usually only 5 icons by 5 icons.

We wish to paint a “button” on a pixel grid, such that the button is centered on the canvas. If the pixel grid is very large, then we want to the button to be roughly 60% of the width of the pixel grid. However, the pixel grid is usually small.
We have the following constraints:

- The button must always be visible (the button must be at least one pixel wide)
- the button must be perfectly symmetric about the center of the pixel grid. (The button cannot be slightly to the left, or slightly the right.)
- the button must be less than or equal to 60% of the width of the pixel grid

We have the following objective:

- make the button as large as possible subject to the above constraints

In a typical programming language, how can we write a function to calculate the optimal button width? The function accepts the pixel grid width as input and the function is to output the button width.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any programming, let’s do some MATH:

Let `screen_width` be a variable denoting the width of the pixel grid.
Let `button_width` be a variable denoting the width of the button.

If order to be perfectly centered, if `screen_width` is odd, then `button_width` must also be odd. Also, if `screen_width` is even then `button_width` is even. Originally, we only had ae 1 pixel minimum for the button. However, that can be extended to a 2 pixel minimum if the pixel grid is an even number of pixels wide.

Below are the results for some example canvas (`screen_width`) sizes:

```
+--------+---------+
| Canvas | Central |
| width  | Button  |
|        | width   |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 1       |
| 2      | 2       |
| 3      | 1       |
| 4      | 2       |
| 5      | 3       |
+--------+---------+
```

Let n = max{integer k such that k less than or equal to 60% of the screen width and k is has the same parity (even or odd) as Screen width.

Let m be a variable such that m = 1 if (screen width is odd) and (m = 2) if screen width is even.

Let `button_width` be min{n, m}
Then `button_width` has all of the desired properties.

### Programming

Now, we finally write some code:

```
int CALC_BUTTON_WIDTH(int screen_width, float fraction) {        
    int bw_lrg = CALC_BUTTON_WIDTH_FOR_LRG_CANVAS(screen_width, fraction);
    int bw_sml = CALC_BUTTON_WIDTH_FOR_SML_CANVAS(screen_width, fraction);
    button width = min(bw_sml, bw_lrg);
    return button_width;
}

int CALC_BUTTON_WIDTH_FOR_SML_CANVAS(int screen_width, float fraction) {

    // sw_pairity --- parity of screen width
    // sw_pairity is 0 if screen width is even
    // sw_pairity is 1 if screen width is odd
    sw_pairity     = screen width % 2;


    // sw_pairity_inv --- inverse of parity of screen width 
    // sw_pairity_inv is 1 if screen width is even
    // sw_pairity_inv is 0 if screen width is odd
    sw_pairity_inv = 1 – sw_pairity;      


    // bw_sml is the button with minimum. 
    // Either 1 or 2 pixels
    // if screen is even number of pixels wide, bw_sml is 1
    // if screen is odd number of pixels wide, bw_sml is 0
    // Example: screen 3 --> button 1
    // Example: screen 4 --> button 2
    //
    // --X-    button not centered!
    // -XX-    okay
    //
    // --X--   okay
    // -XX--   button not centered!

    bw_sml = 1 + sw_pairity_inv;
    return bw_sml;

}

int CALC_BUTTON_WIDTH_FOR_LRG_CANVAS(int screen_width, float fraction) {

    int sw_pairity;
    int bw_lrg;

    sw_pairity  = screen width % 2;
    bw_lrg = floor(fraction * screen_width);
    bw_lrg_parity = bw_lrg % 2;
    correction = (sw_pairity + bw_lrg_parity) % 2;
    bw_lrg = bw_lrg + correction;

    return bw_lrg;
}
```